# How to recognize client's computer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dns

I have a problem recognizing client's computer data. I'm developing an application that requires some king of recongnision of machine client is currently using. I tried

```
 System.Environment.MachineName;
```

and also

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
var add = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
```

, but it always returns data of server computer IIS is working on. Also i tried to get processors and basebords id's but with same result as previous examples.

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            serial = mo["SerialNumber"].ToString();
        }

        ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = mbs.Get();
        string id = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
        {
            id = mo["ProcessorID"].ToString();
        }t
```

System will be used inside a private network(not to be used publicly).

Is there any way to somehow recognize any unique client's computer data in ASP.NET web application development, or .NET simply deny any recognision of client's computer data due to safety?

Thanks

Comment: I think the usual method to do this, is to set a cookie with an GUID or similar, which will get setted the first time the visitor opens the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code runs on the Server, "System" is the Server. In ASP.NET you can get information about who is requesting (the client) with the `Request` object. Try this:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Or this:

```
Request.UserHostName
```

Comment: this return's default gateway address.

Comment: @HodzaNdzaho have tried the second one? Here the reference [HttpRequest.UserHostName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right. I've been browsing the page from different subnet, that's why it was returning default gateway. Then i tried from the computer with the same subnet as server, it worked.